# Is there a way to return misspelled words in a textarea with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, spell-checking, misspelling

I want to make a function that creates a list of the words that are misspelled inside a textarea. Is there a way to get the words that are underlined in red for being misspelled according to the default dictionary/spellchecker?

I know I could do it with a dictionary of 'my own' and check with that, but I'm aiming to do it using the automatic spellchecker textboxes have.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think user agents make that information available to your code. There's nothing in the [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) or [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) interfaces for it, for instance, nor on [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) or [`Navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator). Nothing in the description of the [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck) attribute mentions it. The HTML spec's [*Spelling and grammar checking*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking) section doesn't mention anything.

There may be hope on the horizon though. CSS is adding the [`::spelling-error` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::spelling-error), although there isn't any support for it in browsers yet. Although that wouldn't help you do what you're doing, it indicates that there is at least *some* interest in allowing pages to interact with this information in some way. So it may happen someday.